# CardLayout not running

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, cardlayout

Hello I have tried to create a program that when a button is clicked it will switch JPanel using the CardLayout.

Source:

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class CardDemo extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

CardLayout cl;
JPanel p1, p2, p3, p4, p5;
JButton b1, b2, b3;

public static void main(String args[]) {
    CardDemo d = new CardDemo();

p1 = new JPanel();
    p1.setBackground(Color.red);   //the top panel
    p2 = new JPanel();
    p2.setBackground(Color.blue);  //bottom panel - we never actually see this

    JButton b1 = new JButton("One");    //create the buttons with labels
    JButton b2 = new JButton("Two");
    JButton b3 = new JButton("Three");

    b1.addActionListener(d);     //this object listens for button clicks
    b2.addActionListener(d);
    b3.addActionListener(d);

    p1.add(b1);       //uttons added to the top panel
    p1.add(b2);
    p1.add(b3);

    cl = new CardLayout();     //create the CardLayout object
    p2.setLayout(cl);          //set p2 to use a CardLayout

    JPanel p3 = new JPanel();         //make the three panels that we
    p3.setBackground(Color.green);    //will put into the CardLayout panel
    JPanel p4 = new JPanel();
    p4.setBackground(Color.yellow);   //give them different colours
    JPanel p5 = new JPanel();
    p5.setBackground(Color.cyan);

    p2.add(p3, "One");
    p2.add(p4, "Two");
    p2.add(p5, "Three");

d.setSize(500,400);
d.setVisible(true);
d.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));
d.getContentPane().add(p1);
d.getContentPane().add(p2);
}

/** The actionPerformed method handles button clicks
 */
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String buttonLabel = ((JButton)e.getSource()).getText();
    cl.show(p2, buttonLabel);
}
}
```

When I compile the code I get errors, and I have tried everything to try to get it to work and can't seem to figure out where I am going wrong. I am a beginner to Java by the way and I have probably made a small amateur mistake somewhere.

The error message is below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - non-   static variable p1 cannot be referenced from a static context
at CardDemo.main(CardDemo.java:22)
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: What errors do you receive and what is your specific question?

Comment: You should consider using an IDE like Eclipse or NetBeans. An IDE is a program to write code inside of. These two have syntax highlighting that displays compile time errors as you type for java. Probably would be useful here.

Comment: First rule of programming: read the error message.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Gray Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - non-static variable p1 cannot be referenced from a static context
 at CardDemo.main(CardDemo.java:22)
Java Result: 1

Comment: @JBNizet I assumed that the people from the Forum on here would copy and try to run my program and see for themselves what was wrong

Comment: @JBNizet If people could read the error message and fix their problem what use are you or this whole website? If you read what I wrote rather than just message you can see it says I tried to resolve the problem myself and can't seem to figure it out, so I have resorted to here to try get my problem solved!

Comment: Don't make this assumption. Instead, do your best to make the life of people reading your question and willing to help you, for free, as easy as possible. Just reading the error message is often sufficient to diagnose the problem. And if you're too lazy to paste the complete and exact error message, I won't bother trying to answer your question (and most of the other readers won't either).

Comment: Yeah I am new to this site, sorry for not putting the error message in, I have added it in now and nope I still don't know what to do and how to resolve it

Comment: No problem. Also note that this does not look like a compiler error message, but like a runtime error message. Don's even start to run the program if you still have compilation errors. And read the answer you got. It has a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to assing a member variable inside a static method (main in this one). That won't work. Instance variables can only be assigned on instances.

```
p1 = new JPanel(); //p1 is a member variable
```

You should do like this:
    `d.p1 = new JPanel();` for your example.

But this is the hard way. I would suggest to create a member method and initialize everything inside and call this init method in your main method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    CardDemo cd = new CardDemo();
    cd.init();
}

private void init() {
   p1 = new JPanel();
...
```

Comment: I tried this but now I am getting a non-static error for this one now:getContentPane().add(p1);
 getContentPane().add(p2);

Comment: Yeah resolved that error but getting a blank window with nothing showing up

Comment: Yeah but then I get an error with the d.getContentPane saying it can't find the symbol

Comment: Because there is no d anymore. d refers to `this` when you put it in a member method. How much do you know Java by the way?

Comment: I know the basics, and yeah I changed where it says d to this and it is running now, nice one!

Comment: You need more context about Java, it seems like you're missing fundemantals and trying to work on higher level concepts. I'd suggest studying Java basics like, instances and classes, static methods...

Comment: Yeah you are right I am missing some concepts, but I am doing this for fun really, and I tend to pick things up quicker this way, I can see what you have done and it makes sense to me now, I won't make this mistake again in the future now.